# GoogleMap draw markers on CameraMove

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an android app and I want to refresh displayed markers when the user moves the map camera depending on current LatLngBounds. 
The problem is that CameraMove event fires too often. Even a small move with finger triggers tens of events.
GetData method is a bit expensive so I don't want to call it too often.

Is there some proper way to draw the data only when the map has stopped 'moving'?

My app is in C# (Xamarin) but every help in Java/Kotlin is welcomed.

```
    public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
    {
        googleMap.CameraMove += GglMap_CameraMove;
    }

    private void GglMap_CameraMove(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var googleMap = (GoogleMap)sender;
        var bounds = googleMap.Projection.VisibleRegion.LatLngBounds;
        var zoom = googleMap.CameraPosition.Zoom;

        if (zoom>18)
        {
            var data = GetData(bounds); 
            DrawMarkers(data);
        }
    }
```

Also there is a CameraMoveStarted event that fires only once but there is no CameraMoveEnded.

Comment: There is a [GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnCameraIdleListener) that you can set to refresh the markers whenever the camera stops moving. I'm not sure if it's available in Xamarin though.

Comment: Thanks, that's the event I was looking for.